# SlideDown the parent of a certain element, SlideUp all the ones that are not

Tags: jquery, html

I have a series of **ul**, by cliking a button I'm trying to slideDown the ones that are parent of the **li.newlist** element, and slideUp all the others that are not. I manage to slideDown the ones I want, but I'm not sure how to define the second action, since I can't use .not(). It's probably something very easy, thank you.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li class="newlist">B</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
</ul>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('button').click(function () { 
        $('li.newlist').parent().slideDown(400);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/v6wtv/)**</kbd>

```
$('button').click(function () { 
  $('ul').has('.newlist').stop().slideDown(400).siblings('ul').stop().slideUp(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this first:

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children('.newlist').length == 0) {
         $(this).slideUp(400);
    }
});
```

This will slide up only the options that do not contain a `.newlist` item.